# get each field from chcsv parser

Tags: ios, csv, ios6

When I use CHCSV parser:from this code from https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser :

```
NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVString:lunchFile
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                            error:&err];
```

I get the below array

```
(
        (
        Date,
        Item,
        Desc
        "price#",
        "add#",
        rate,
        "",
        ""
    ),
        (
        "12/10/12",
        abc,
        "abc equipment",
        abc678,
        "Y.7.A",
        "555,007.21",
        "",
        ""
    ),
```

How do I get value from each field ?.The first line is column name and it needs to populate sqlite db.I am a noob in this How do I get the value from each field. I am using fmdb to out the fields in sqlite.db.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it :

```
NSArray *s1 =  [a objectAtIndex:4];


 NSLog(@"  element :  %@", [s1 componentsJoinedByString:@","]);    

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < s1.count; i++) {
        NSString* string = [s1 objectAtIndex:i];
         NSLog(@" This is : %d  %@",i , string);

    }
```